# error con funcion apply

Tags: r

Me surgió el siguiente problema:

tengo una matriz con varias columnas y quiero contar las celdas que no son na de las ultimas 6 celdas de cada columna (siendo 0 el menor numero posible y 6 el mayor).

Para resolverlo plantee la siguiente función con un `apply`, pero me da un vector con valores incorrectos como resultado. Agradecería mucho una ayuda. Aquí está mi código:

```
comprobacion<-function(datos,x){
  G<-tail(datos[,x],6)!="NA"
  sum(G, na.rm = T)
}

sumas<-apply(ret.2,2,comprobacion,datos=ret.2)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, muy clara la respuesta. Me has ayudado mucho.

Answer (score 1):

dami,

bienvenido. Siempre es buena idea presentar al menos una parte de tus datos para facilitar las respuestas. De todos modos con la descripción creo que es suficiente. Creé unos datos que tienen (creo) la misma estructura que los tuyos y con esos busqué una solución.

## Los datos

```
set.seed(2018)
matriz <- matrix(runif(100, 1, 20)[sample(x = c(NA, TRUE), 
                                          prob = c(0.3, 0.7), 
                                          size = 50, 
                                          replace = TRUE)
                                   ], 
                  ncol = 10)
```

Este código crea un vector de número aleatorios de largo 100, le agrega 0.3 de `NA` aleatorios y lo convierte en una matriz de 10*10.

## La función

```
comprobacion <- function(x) {
  sum(is.na(tail(x,6)))
}

apply (matriz, 2, comprobacion)
```

## Explicación

Los valores `NA` en R son valores lógicos (aunque diferentes de `TRUE` y `FALSE`). Por lo tanto no es posible verificar igualdad con `== "NA"`. En ese caso tendría un `TRUE` cuando está la cadena de caracteres `"NA"`, pero no es lo que te interesa.

Para verificar igualdad con `NA` se utiliza la función `is.na()`. Si a `is.na()` le pasamos un vector nos va a regresar otro vector de igual largo con `TRUE` en las mismas posiciones en las que encontró `NA` y `FALSE`  cuando encontró otra cosa.

Una propiedad de R es que cuando cohercionamos un vector lógico a numérico (eso es lo que hacemos implícitamente con el `sum()`) los `TRUE` se consideran 1 y los `FALSE` se consideran 0. Por eso al sumar te la cantidad de valores `NA`, son los `TRUE` que silenciosamente pasaron a 1.

`tail()`, como bien estabas usando en tu función original, muestra los últimos elementos de una estructura de datos, en este caso los 6 últimos.

Entonces si sumamos el vector lógico resultante de la prueba `is.na()` de los últimos 6 elementos de cada columna obtenemos el número de `NA` en esa ubicación.

`apply` se encarga de pasar una función por cada columna --o fila- de una matriz. Le entrega ese dato ya separado a la función `comprobación`, así que no es necesario indicarle a `comprobacion` que opere por filas, hago subsets, o especificarle los datos. La función  que pasamos con `apply` solo verá vectores. Esto facilita las cosas, no es necesario que nuestra función --en este caso `comprobación`- maneje esa parte de la ejecución de código, la programamos y testeamos con un vector y funcionará bien para matrices o data frames. Por eso no es necesario especificar que es `x` ni en la función ni en la llamada de `apply`.

> Si tus datos son diferentes o la función no está haciendo lo que necesitas por favor mencionalo en un comentario o reformula la pregunta para hacerla más específica. Seguro hay una solución.

Comment: Otra forma algo más compacta podría ser: `colSums(is.na(tail(matriz,6)),na.rm = TRUE)`. Saludos,

Comment: Sí, te evitarías el `apply`. De hecho podría ser más corto, me parece que en este caso el `na.rm=` no es necesario, porque estás sumando un vector lógico salido de `is.na` y por lo tanto jamás debería tener `NA`.

Comment: Si, es cierto, es la costumbre :-)